# use resource in jar created by maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, resources

I have a maven project in eclipse with `App.java` in in `my.package` in `src/main/java` and a couple of pictures in `my.package.resources`

I looked in the jar and the structure is like this:

```
MyApp
|- chrriis \\ library stuff
|- com \\ stuff with google and sun
|- javax
|- META-INF \\ contains MANIFEST.MF and other maven stuff
|- org \\ contains most of my used libraries
|- my
|  |- package
|  |  | App.class
|  |  | App$1.class
|  |  |- resources
|  |  |  |-picture.png
```

When I load a picture like:

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
p1.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(App.class.getResource("resources"+File.separator+"picture.png"))));
```

and run it in eclipse, it works fine. But when I Export it to a runnable jar it give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

But when I move the picture.png to `my.package` and do
`App.class.getResource("picture.png")` it works fine.

I tried this four solutions but they did not work for me:
([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464816/maven-packaging-images-in-the-root-of-the-jar-file)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155946/create-executable-jar-from-classes-and-images-using-eclipse)) ([3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053214/eclipse-and-maven-resources-in-jar)) ([4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCoed3MKpEA))

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the images in a separate sub folder from the class that is using them?

Comment: Well I read that it is a better idea to have resources in another folder. But a using sub folder was the only working way for me, so that the pictures are included in the jar.

Comment: Then how is it that [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053214/eclipse-and-maven-resources-in-jar) does not work for you? Can you provide a bit more details about the above mentioned solutions and where you run into problems with it?

Comment: Does it work in the sub-folder case if you replace `File.separator` by `"/"`? The Javadoc for Class.getResource() suggests that it expects '/' to separate folder names rather than the system-specific separator - which looks like it might be '\\' on your system.

Comment: @hotzst apparently I made the same mistake in all aproaches. I used either `File.seperator` or `\\`. Using `/` worked.

Comment: @sisyphus yep replacing `File.seperator` by `/` worked. Since I use window it used `\\` -.- thanks.